# v8::Isolate::New null access violation

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8, libv8

I'm using V8 32-bit Version 4.10.253 compiled with Visual Studio 2015.

I'm trying to run the example that Google has at: 
[Chrome V8 - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started#audience)

But when I try to run it, I get:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in V8Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
violation executing location 0x00000000.
```

I get this when the following is executed:

```
Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
```

**My project settings:**

To get the project to compile in debug, I set the runtime library to:

```
Multi-threaded Debug /MTd.
```

I include the v8 include directory under additional include directories.

Lastly, I include the following libraries:

```
icuuc.lib icui18n.lib v8_libplatform.lib v8_external_snapshot.lib
v8_base_3.lib v8_base_2.lib v8_base_1.lib v8_base_0.lib v8_libbase.lib
winmm.lib
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I feel stupid. I didn't finish reading the rest of the tutorial. You must copy all the .bin files where your executable is stored. Specifically:

```
natives_blob.bin
snapshot_blob.bin
```

V8 will crash at Isolate::New if you do not.

Comment: That's why I use no_snapshot.  It's MINUTELY slower on startup, but you don't have to deal with having the right bin files -- which change based on debug/32 vs 64bit/version of V8/etc.   Easier to wait the additional .1s or so (when I measured) and not deal with them ever again.  Just don't link external_snapshot and link no_snapshot instead.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip, I'm going to have to give that a shot.

Comment: Also, if you're not, make sure you're developing against the debug builds (make x64.debug) -- it gives better failure information before things crash.  It's not great, but it's quite a bit better.   Also, I think the stack traces are even a bit better, too.

Comment: Yep, if you link with v8_nosnapshot, you dont have to worry about copying over the bin files. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I sure hope so -- otherwise I've been doing something VERY strange all this time :)